Work path from photoshop keeps deforming in Illustrator
When I make work path in Photoshop and export it to Illustrator, Path connects to wrong anchor point, deforming the shape. Is there any way to fix this problem?



I'd suspect the work path has too many anchors. Smoothing the select first may help.

welcome on Graphic Design SE! The issue you're facing seem to be that the path is open once exported to illustrator, whence the vertical line connecting two points far apart. You might be interested in vectorizing a rasterized version of the path, or learning to draw with brushes in Illustrator.
